# Find values that overlap in two arrays efficiently and save them out in a third array

Tags: c#

Assuming I have the 2 arrays...

```
string[] a = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "h", "i", "j", "k"};
string[] b = {"a", "c", "d", "e", "g"};
string[] c;
```

I want to create a resulting array c which has a list of the values that overlap. So for the above I would get the following result:

```
c = {"a", "c", "d", "e"};
```

How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way - which is also efficient - is to use LINQ's [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) method:

```
c = a.Intersect(b).ToArray();
```

This will use a `HashSet<T>` internally to keep track of values which can still be returned. See my [Edulinq blog post on `Intersect`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-16-intersect-and-build-fiddling.aspx) for more details.

Note that the result is effectively a *set* - the order isn't guaranteed (although in practice it will be the order the elements appear in `a`) and each value will only occur *once*, even if it's repeated in both original arrays.

Note that if you only need to iterate over the result, it would be more efficient not to turn it into an array at all:

```
IEnumerable<string> intersection = a.Intersect(b);
```

EDIT: To find the indexes, you could *either* do some trickery with LINQ, or just do it fairly simply iteratively:

```
HashSet<string> remaining = new HashSet<string>(b);
List<Tuple<string, int>> pairs = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    if (remaining.Remove(a[i]))
    {
        pairs.Add(Tuple.Of(a[i], i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there also a way to get a list of indices of array a for the ones that overlap?

Comment: @rotaercz: From which array? The first? You *could* get them fairly inefficiently but easily, but if I'd known you wanted indices I'd probably have started off with a different approach...

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of modifying the code that would be provided for the indices but I don't really see anything I can modify in yours. :)

Comment: @rotaercz: Okay - will add something appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) method in Linq does what you need.

```
 c = a.Intersect(b).ToArray();
```